# What does it mean if expire is set to null in a cache table?

Tags: 8, caching

I am looking at the documentation for the expire field in the cache tables and the documentation in CacheBackendInterface.php says:

> @param int `$expire`
> One of the following values:
>
> - CacheBackendInterface::CACHE_PERMANENT: Indicates that the item should not be removed unless it is deleted explicitly.
> - A Unix timestamp: Indicates that the item will be considered invalid after this time, i.e. it will not be returned by `get()` unless `$allow_invalid` has been set to `TRUE`. When the item has expired, it may be permanently deleted by the garbage collector at any time.

When I look in a cache table, for example *cache_render*, I see that many entries have NULL in the *expire* column and I noticed it only get clear on a complete cache clear, such as after running `drush cr`.

What does a null value set for the *expire* column in a cache table mean?

Comment: I don't see entries having NULL in `cache_render` and I don't see a problem if there were any. Cache entries are not deleted if they become invalid. Cron deletes them after a while, and any cache entry having an expire value less than the current time and not CACHE_PERMANENT are deleted.

Comment: @4k4 thank you. I need to do more digging to see where the null entries are coming from. I suspect a contrib module. I found this after noticing blocks were not updating after editing them until I cleared the cache, more specifically cache render.

Comment: This would be a different issue. A cache item gets cleared after editing if it has the correct cache tag.

Answer (score 1):

Any value for the *expire* column that is different from [`CacheBackendInterface::CACHE_PERMANENT`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cache%21CacheBackendInterface.php/constant/CacheBackendInterface%3A%3ACACHE_PERMANENT/8.9.x) (-1) is considered a timestamp, indicating when the cache entry could be deleted. In the case of `NULL`, the value means the cache entry could be deleted in any moment.
As [@4k4 said in his comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/277848/what-does-it-mean-if-expire-is-set-to-null-in-a-cache-table#comment345170_277848), data in cache tables are deleted when cron tasks run, and that doesn't necessarily means immediately.

The only issue with `NULL` is whether a module is using a not initialized variable which is expected to contain the expiration time. In that case, the cached value is kept in cache less than required.